# Changing span text value JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, reactjs, angularjs

[image]

I'm trying to target that span (please see pic) of ID="DNTCaptchaInputText-error" I want to be able to change the inner text that says, "This field is required" to a more custom error message like, "please type out the security code".

so far I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText-error').innerHTML = 'please type out the security 
code';
```

and also tried

```
document.getElementsByClassName('DNTCaptchaInputText-error')[0].innerHTML = 'please type out 
security code.';
```

none of that seems to work so far, any idea please?

Thank you.

//EDIT

still not working here's the code

```
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-prepend"><span 
class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span></span><input 
autocomplete="off" class="text-box form-control input-validation-error" 
data-required-msg="none" data-val="true" data-val-required="none" 
dir="ltr" id="DNTCaptchaInputText" name="DNTCaptchaInputText" 
placeholder="Enter Code" required="required" type="text" value="" aria- 
describedby="DNTCaptchaInputText-error" aria-invalid="true"></div>

<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg- 
for="DNTCaptchaInputText" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span 
id="DNTCaptchaInputText-error" class="">This field is required</span> 
</span>
```

I seriously don't get why  `document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText-error').innerHTML = 'New text here';` isn't working! Keeping saying cannot set innerHTML property of null and I've tried all the suggested answer here.

Comment: "doesn't work" how? Any error messages?

Comment: Is the id `DNTCaptchaInputText-error` the only id of that type? `id` tags must be specific to 1 element. It could be that you are not changing the correct element, your first example should have worked fine

Comment: To add to the above point regarding multiple `id`, also check that you're executing your JS code *after* the DOM has loaded.

Comment: The error I get in console log is, "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" basically, I managed to change the placeholder in the input field which works fine:  document.getElementsByName('DNTCaptchaInputText')[0].placeholder = 'Enter code';     but getting to change the span seems like a nightmare, it's a ReCaptcha I implemented called, DNTCaptcha,  so the span is added automatically, just need to target it with JS so I can throw out a custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it's work.

```
document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText').textContent='please type out the security code';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried but doesn't work still getting the error in console, "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". This is a span on an input field name, "DNTCaptchaInputText" and the span shows when there is no value entered in the field and user hits submit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, you just need to check the element is exists or not at the time when you playing with it.

**Solution 1:**

Check if the dom is loaded properly. Use `window.onload` event and put your code inside it.

**Solution 2:**

add a flag to check if the element is existing and put your code inside the block.

also, check both working solutions in the snippet below.

```js
// will fire when everything will be loaded
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText-error').textContent = 'This message will show when window is loaded';
}

// just checking null for selected dom
if (document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText-error')) {
  document.getElementById('DNTCaptchaInputText-error').innerHTML = 'This is dynamic message';
}
```

```html
<p id="DNTCaptchaInputText-error">I am the default error</p>
```

Note: `window.onload` will override the value because it executes after the window is loaded. read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, didn't work unfortunately - please see the edited version.

Comment: What error you're getting after applying this trick? and what solution you tried?

Comment: It's a weird error, kept saying, "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", if I changed .innerHTML to .textContext the error message would be: "Cannot set property 'textContext' of null". The input field along with the span (I'm trying to target) is generated automatically as the solution I'm trying to implement is using dnt-recaptcha found here: https://github.com/VahidN/DNTCaptcha.Core (all works fine just need to specifically change this field   asp-validation-error-message="Please enter the security code as a number." value to a custom message) if that helps?

Comment: did you try the solution 1?

Comment: Yeah tried both mate just wouldn't changed - I got the placeholder texts changed by using this: document.getElementsByName('DNTCaptchaInputText')[0].placeholder = 'Please enter code as shown'; But that error span is refusing just don't know as I've tried everything. Solution 1 doesn't show error in console log but just doesn't show the text.

Comment: ok, try to select by `querySelector` with and ID/Class and set attribute. `document.querySelector('#captachInputID').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Please enter code as shown')`